# TagHelper for passing route values as part of a link

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

When specifying `asp-controller` and `asp-action` on a link, what's the syntax for also passing an id attribute?

E.g. If I wanted to link to the edit URL for a given object, the required URL would be `/user/edit/5` for example.

Is there a method to achieve this using TagHelpers, or do we still have to fall back to `@Html.ActionLink()`?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You can use the attribute prefix `asp-route-` to prefix your route variable names.

Example: `<a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="10" asp-route-foo="bar">Edit</a>`

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, because my "asp-route-foobar" didn't match my route: "routes.MapRoute("yearNoCombo", template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{foobar?}/{whatever1}/{whatever2}"); - the route-names must match. HTH others.

Comment: In addition to the above comment you do need to ensure that your routes are setup correctly to avoid the route bit appearing as a parameter in the HTML Either using MapRoute or route annotations on your methods

Comment: @Kiran can I pass object in asp-route dynamic

Comment: @user123456 This can be done with a `Dictionary<string, string>` passed to the `all-route-data` parameter.

Answer (score 47):

I'd like to suggest a combination of the other two answers, but with a bit of extra clarification.

You will use an attribute prefix `asp-route-{name}` where `{name}` is the name of the route parameter you want to use. In other words, if the number 5 in your route is passed into the controller as an ID value, you could have:

```
<a asp-controller="User" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Edit</a>
```

or if the parameter you wanted to pass to the route was item.UserName then

```
<a asp-controller="User" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-username="@item.UserName">Edit</a>
```

And if you had both parameters then

```
<a asp-controller="User" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id" asp-route-username="@item.UserName">Edit</a>
```

Comment: This definitely made more sense to me than the others. Can you also have multiple asp-route-{parameter name} in the same <a></a> ?
This helped my issue with it Not binding properly trying to send a foreign key CompanyId back as it was using Id and placing it in the Order primary key Id instead.

Comment: Yes, you can. According to http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/06/01/mvc-6-anchor-tag-helper.aspx   You can specify values for as many parameters as you need using attributes with the *asp-route-* prefix. I don't think you can have two parameters with the same name - there is a feature request/issue about that here https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4560

Comment: So if I read that right, currently there is a way to pass lists only in the action helper method and not in the anchor tag helpers.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show passing two parameters in the anchor taghelper. Is that better?

Comment: Didn't really need to. I of course didn't know of the terminology used in your links when I was seeking answers to my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42983224/3527398) about passing lists back.

Comment: Worked for me. I implemented for pagination

Comment: Worked for me after banging my head trying to figure it out. This is great.

Answer (score 5):

you can pass custom ID using below code:

```
<a asp-controller="User" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Edit</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest one more way for Razor view to use model value using @Html.actionlink in jsp

```
var URLvalue='@Html.ActionLink("UserString", "action", new { routeValueName1 = "__value1__", routeValueName2="__value2__" }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-default", @role = "button" })'
     .replace('__value1__', Model.somevalue).replace('__value2__',  Model.somevalue);
```

you can use URLvalue where ever you want to in jsp or jquery.