# Asp action route data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In the old version of MVC 5 I could do this to pass route parameters

```
@Html.ActionLink("New item", "Suggestion", new ProductSuggestion() { Username = Model.Username }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
```

I am trying to get this to work with the new asp-action method and I figgured out I could do this as a workaround. But what is the correct syntax for this?

```
    @{ 
        var a = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Username", Model.Username } };
    }

    <a asp-action="Suggestion" asp-all-route-data="a" class="btn btn-default">New item</a>
```

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30020892/taghelper-for-passing-route-values-as-part-of-a-link) could help you.

Comment: There is no MVC6 (anymore)!! https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/01/19/asp-net-5-is-dead-introducing-asp-net-core-1-0-and-net-core-1-0/

Comment: That actually doesn't say anything about what MVC will be called. .Net Core 1.0 is just the framework.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TagHelper for passing route values as part of a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30020892/taghelper-for-passing-route-values-as-part-of-a-link)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Dave Paquette did a nice write up about many of the TagHelpers.
Here's the one for the anchor tag helper: http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/06/01/mvc-6-anchor-tag-helper.aspx

Essentially you can do

```
<a asp-controller="MyController" asp-action="MyAction" asp-route-myvar="myValue">
```

Which will then provide `myValue` to a controller method like

```
public Task<IActionResult> MyAction(string myVar) { 
...
}
```

Be aware that you cannot do this with complex types that easily.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you still can.  I think what's missing is the inclusion of the controller in your anchor above.

```
@{ 
    var a = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Username", Model.Username } };
}

<a asp-controller="{Controller}" asp-action="Suggestion" asp-all-route-data="a" class="btn btn-default">New item</a>
```